# Recursion in Python returning an empty list

Tags: list, recursion

First time posting. I need to filter through a tuple that can contain more tuples and lists within themselves. I then need to get the max value. Does anyone know why my int_storage list is empty?

def max_val(t): 
    int_storage = []
    tuple_storage = []

```
if type(t) == int:
    int_storage.append(t)
    return int_storage

for i in t:
    if type(t) == int:
        int_storage.append(i)

    if type(i) != int:
        for tup in i:
            tuple_storage.append(tup)
        return max_val(tuple_storage)
return max(int_storage)
```

test = ((5, (1,2), [[1],[2]]))
print(max_val(test))

Comment: by the way, if you return max_val(tuple_storage) there, the for loop will be terminated as soon as it come across not-an-int variable and the function will immediately return.

Comment: So i suggest keeping only max_val(tuple_storage), since return here is not necessary and also mess up your recursion code.

Answer (score 0):

First, this should be i instead of t, i believe it is just a small typo.

```
for i in t:
   if type(t) == int: #the t on this line
```

Second, you do realize that your int_storage and tuple_storage is just a local variable?

As soon as you enter the max_val() the second time, int_storage and tuple_storage will be whole new variables and it will have value of [] as you have defined them to be.
I suggest you do some research on scope for more information.

Also making int_storage ,tuple_storage global will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi thank you for your assistance. I have watched a few videos on scope but I cant still understand as to why it returns an empty list if the lists are local, it doesn't iterate through them?

Comment: It still iterate through them, but not the way you want to.

Comment: .Let me explain your algorithm in the first recursion: max_val(test) , since test is not int, we'll skip the first condition and go to the loop, here you first add 5 to int_storage, because it is int. Next iteration: (1,2) is  not an int, so we go through the second loop.

Comment: for tup in i: we add 1 and 2 to the tuple_storage. and the we call another max_val(tuple_storage). Then we will go into the 2nd recursion and we will keep adding number into int_storage and tuple_storage?

Comment: But here's the thing: the int_storage and tuple_storage in the 2nd recursion: (maxval(tuple_storage)) is not the int_storage and tuple_storage in the 1st recursion ( maxval(test)) because they belong in different function, thus different scope.

Comment: the int_storage and tuple_storage in the 2nd recursion will be empty as you have set them to be in the beginning of the function max_val

Comment: @JedCornish and also check my comment above. Again, the second iteration : (1,2) will end max_val(test) as soon as it reach """"return max_val(tuple_storage)"""" although the function hasn't iterate through [[1],[2]], because